# How can we call the "Environments" at a nightclub?

Tags: vocabulary

Can I use "environment" to describe the sections in which some night clubs are divided?

It sounds so strange to me.

For example,
"Moon nightclub offers three environments, each featuring a kind of music!"

I've also found the word "ambiances", but the online dictionary says it is a rare word.

Comment: Maybe "themes"?

Comment: "Environment" isn't strange in this context. It's almost a "term of art" in the nightclub business. You'll see it used frequently, as for instance **[here,](https://www.reviewjournal.com/entertainment/nightlife/lavo-offers-variety-of-environments-including-nightclub-lounge-restaurant/)** **[here,](https://www.reddit.com/r/cardistry/comments/53t905/most_striking_decks_for_dark_nightclub/)** and **[here.](http://hakkasanlv.com/private-events/)** I wouldn't look for a substitute if I were writing promotional literature for a nightclub. It's perfect and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **sections** comes to mind first.

You'd often hear about a **VIP section** at a fancy night club, which is an area for special guests that not just anybody is allowed to enter. It might be up on a balcony, or divided by a velvet rope. And other parts of the club could similarly be called sections as well.

However, depending on the club's layout, **rooms** might be more appropriate. "Rooms" denotes that the sections are mostly or completely divided by walls. And if the VIP section was actually closed off by walls and a door or curtain, it might be more properly described as a **VIP room**.

For use in your example scenario, the different sections of the Moon nightclub might each have their own **atmosphere** or **vibe**.

If a club's music and atmosphere are pretty much the same throughout, you may just refer to the specific parts of the club instead of giving a general name for the parts. For example, a club might have a **dancefloor**, a **bar**, and a **seating area** or **tables**.